# Wireless Router Downloads Kill my Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router, bandwidth

So I run on a standard Charter Internet, 30 MBPS. Anytime I download something though, via steam or battle.net my internet completely drops out and only focuses on the download - which is only 1.1MB/s at a time.

I have a Netgear N300 Wirless Router and anytime I run my internet through that, my download speeds drop to 12MBPS. What do I need to do so I can get the same speeds through my Netgear Wireless as I do my Charter Router?

Also, I'm talking about getting 12MBPS through the wire, not wirelessly.

Comment: Don't those services use bittorrent or similar techniques. You would have to use some tool to monitor the traffic and connections to see what happens on your side of the network but it may well be some limitation technique on the ISP side.

Comment: Well if I plug it directly into the Charter router I receive correct speeds which is why I believe it has something to do with the netgear router.

Comment: 1. Call charter make sure everything is running fine on their end. 2. Buy a new router and see if the problem continues.

Comment: Talked to charter - everything was fine on all tests. Is spending 50+ on a new router really the solution here?

Comment: it would be the fastest solution to isolate the problem, also no one said you have to keep the new router. Otherwise i would say call netgear and ask them why it's happening.

Comment: Calling to charter won't help if the router has been identified as the likely problem. I'm using routers flashed with OpenWRT so I can at least check what's going on.

Comment: In this case nobody can help you unless you have more information about how/when the problem starts and how/when it stops.

Comment: It's consistent - all day every day.

Comment: If your router is consistently slow, it may well be... erm... too slow to handle the traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Router was telling me I had the most up-to-date firmware, but in order to use that updated frimware I needed to reset my router to factory settings. Once I did this I started to get the correct speeds.

Comment: Hmm, so it was a software problem.